# SWF Scaling and Positioning, Width 100% with Height auto adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, scaling

I am trying to have an SWF fill the browser 100% in width, and auto adjust for the height forcing the page to scroll if necessary. I have tried the following:

```
<object width="100%" height="auto" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="map">
```

as well as:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="map">
```

The first just adjusts the SWF to be 200 by 200px (not entirely sure why), and the second works as to be expected, but obviously only fills up 100% of the height. I would like, for example, a 600px x 1000px SWF to fill the width, and maintain the aspect ratio for the height. To see the bottom of the SWF the user should be forced to scroll.

Comment: I believe you would have to set this up by using ExternalInterface to communicate from Flash->Javascript, then set the div height that way. There's no way to detect a stage width of a swf from HTML or JS, so you have to push the calculation out of Flash via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this. Since I know the size of my SWF, and I don't need to make this dynamic, I have done the following (thank you for the inspiration jpea):

```
// resize the flash DIV for the window width
$("#map").css("height", $(window).width());

// add listener to resize flash on window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#map").css("height", $(window).width());
});
```

My SWF is square. Obviously if it had a different aspect ratio I would just add a multipler before $(window).width().